# Comments for Elsevier paper proof

Tags: publications

I have just corrected my first paper and I might have done something very wrong.

Using the website provided by Elsevier, I corrected everything regarding words and sentences, in addition to small changes in the equations. But, some changes were not possible for me to do, maybe the website had some built-in prevention. For example I couldn't delete and add equations, and I couldn't properly change the layout of the equations (Some equations were cut in half, and some were longer than the text width), also one of the tables needed some changes but I couldn't do them in the website!

So, I wrote multiple comments for the copy-editor regarding these changes. But does this mean that he will do them properly?

Since I will not have the chance to see the changes before publication. I fear that the copy-editor will not make the proper changes! And I might end up with a Frankenstein paper.

Sorry if the question is silly, but I have no experience in this.

Comment: Are you sure you won't be able to see the changes before publication? Even when I've dealt with incompetent copyeditors (which is to say on multiple occasions), they have given me a final version to approve or suggest further changes to.

Comment: @academic Honestly I have no idea. The email I received contained the following sentence:((Kindly note that now we have received your corrections, your article is considered finalised and further amendments are no longer possible.))

Comment: Email them and complain. "Actually, I would like to see the corrected manuscript. When you are finished, would you please send this to me so that I can verify that everything was done correctly?"

Comment: Why on Earth are you asking us rather than someone at Elsevier?! This boggles my mind.

Comment: @user2705196 I emailed them. Plus, as you can figure out from the OP, I have no experience. I wanted to know if all journals take the same procedures  in general or not. Because I am working on another paper as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is very unlikely that any reputable publisher won't review your changes and get back to you if anything seems wrong.

However, if you have contacted the copy-editor, they are also warned that it needs a look. Relax for now, I think. You may have more work to do, of course.

They likely deal with similar things about once a week (day?).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What scared me was the email they sent to me regarding the submission of the corrections. Which included the following sentence: ((Kindly note that now we have received your corrections, your article is considered finalised and further amendments are no longer possible.))

Comment: I suspect that has intent more like "the web system is now locked". But it would be foolish of them to automate the production from your submission forward with no human intervention.